# Why is the datasheet showing VGS at absolute maximum?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm looking at [IRLZ44N datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/sihlz44.pdf).

In the ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM section it is listed that for VGS it is 5V. However in the SPECIFICATIONS section below VGS threshold is listed as 1V to 2V.

At the same time in the ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM section the continuous drain current is given as 36A to 50A at 5V VGS.

Isn't the absolute maximum a value that you should normally stay away from to prolong the component's lifetime? I understand that this is in the absolute maximums section which is probably why they put such test conditions to achieve maximum results but if you go down to the SPECIFICATIONS section you'll see that RDSon is also given at 5V and 4V VGS.

Excuse my ignorance but this is slightly confusing to me. If my assumption is correct that you should stay away from the 5V VGS then how can I calculate the expected RDSon at 1V to 2V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute maximum voltage rating of Vgs for the IRLZ44N is +-10V. Above this rating the device could be damaged

[image]

The Vgs threshold for guaranteed to be ON is 2V and the voltage for the device to be guaranteed to be OFF is 1V

[image]

Driving this device with 5V Gate-Source potential is perfectly fine and is a good choice to ensure the device is ON

Comment: How did I see +-10 as 5?! *facepalm*

Comment: :) easily done.